# C++ on Windows: function to get allocated memory?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-leaks

I'm coding in C++, using Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7.

My application have a memory leak, I can see it with the system monitor.

I need to discovery it in the code.

Does it exist a function that return the amount of memory allocated to the calling process?

Comment: Knowing how much memory you have allocated won't help you find the leak.

Comment: @ColeJohnson That's neither a good advice neither a helpful comment. OP, see [Memory Leak Detection on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: I would prefer to have a function like `getAllocatedMem()` to call before and immediately after some function calls just to se if them release all the memory. You suggestion is a good one, but i'm using this code as a library and i don't know how to debug a running library.

Comment: I don't think such a function exists and it wouldn't be an easy solution. If the code where you are trying to find the leak is a library, try to make multiple calls to the functions you suspect are the cause of the problem and see when the memory consumption explodes: trial and error.

Comment: @Cicada: This method can produce insane amount of false positives. The dude might need allocation profiler or custom memory manager.

Answer (score 4):

There *is* a MSVC-specific solution to memleak detection

```
// enable memory leaks detection
#if !defined(NDEBUG)
HANDLE hLogFile = CreateFile( "log.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                              NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL );
#endif

_CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ASSERT, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE | _CRTDBG_MODE_WNDW  | _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG );
_CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_WARN, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE   | _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG );
_CrtSetReportMode( _CRT_ERROR, _CRTDBG_MODE_FILE  | _CRTDBG_MODE_WNDW  | _CRTDBG_MODE_DEBUG );

_CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_ASSERT, hLogFile );
_CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_WARN,   hLogFile );
_CrtSetReportFile( _CRT_ERROR,  hLogFile );

int tmpDbgFlag = _CrtSetDbgFlag( _CRTDBG_REPORT_FLAG );
tmpDbgFlag |= _CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF;
tmpDbgFlag |= _CRTDBG_DELAY_FREE_MEM_DF;
tmpDbgFlag |= _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF;
_CrtSetDbgFlag( tmpDbgFlag );

if ( BlockIndex > 0 )
{
    _CrtSetBreakAlloc( BlockIndex );
}
```

This creepy code enables file protocol of all the unallocated blocks. Of course, it is deeply tied with the debug version of MSVCRT